# Python: I can not call jupyter notebook

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook

I have installed `jupyter` via `pip3` on mac.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

If I call it I have:

```
-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/jupyter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Looks like it's pointing to python 2.7 and you've used `pip3` to install it

Comment: Its clear from the error message that python is looking for jupyter under python 2.7. What command did you use to install and how are you trying to call jupyter?

Comment: You should learn about `virtualenv`, or `conda` environments - this topic can be a little intimidating at first - but with the current state of python its an absolute must for any python developer beyond the very basic level.

Answer (score 0):

You should start using python environments, so that `pip` and `jupyter` and `python` are using same version of python, but for a temporary "quick fix", do the following:

```
python3 -m jupyter notebook
```